# Why is PTVS so slow?

Tags: python, performance, debugging, visual-studio-2015, ptvs

VS2015 with the l&g PTVS looks great.

But any non-trivial project runs about 20-50 times slower under a debugger (F5) than without one (Ctrl-F5), which makes it totally unusable for debugging.

Any idea why? Is there any way to accelerate the debugger?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/749

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround, try mixed-mode debugging - it is significantly faster (but also more limited).